# Strange behaviour when using SqlDataReader, StreamWriter and FileStream in MVC application vs Console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, streamwriter, sqldatareader

I created a method (`OutputFile`) that takes in data using a `SqlDataReader` and then outputs it to a local file using a `StreamWriter`.

To test that the method output the correct data I created a console application and when the function is called from this it takes roughly **4 minutes** which was expected as the stored procedure involved returns a lot of rows (~200,000).

```
public void OutputFile(string query, string path, params object[] parameters)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Open connection
            con.Open();

            Debug.WriteLine("Starting FileStream");

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Execute Reader");

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Writing Files");

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
                            int charsRead = 0;

                            using (TextReader data = reader.GetTextReader(0))
                            {
                                charsRead = data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                if (charsRead > 0)
                                {
                                    writer.WriteLine(buffer, 0, charsRead);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I moved the method into my ASP.NET MVC application the execution time increased greatly. The first time I ran the application it took **14 minutes** to output the file and the second time it took **30 minutes**. I have included the output from the debug windows below.

When running the application I made sure to turn check thrown CLR exceptions, but none were thrown.

Thanks in for advance for any help that can explain why this issue is occurring.

Additional notes about the ASP.NET MVC application (the console application did not include these references)

- Uses Entity Framework and Unity Framework
- Uses Glimpse

Debug output from the file that is produced in 14 minutes

```
Starting FileStream
Execute Reader
The thread 0x56c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1194 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x568 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x13f8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xb6c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Writing Files
The thread 0xfa8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x136c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

Debug output from the file that is produced in 30 minutes

```
Starting FileStream
Execute Reader
The thread 0x1290 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1030 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x11cc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1310 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1d4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xbb8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x179c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1390 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x169c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x16a0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1424 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x16e8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x14f0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1458 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x17f8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1094 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1484 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1540 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1694 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x17c8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1660 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1764 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1548 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x172c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x17d8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1674 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1380 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
Writing Files
The thread 0x16a8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

Comment: What says SQL Server profiler? Does SQL code executes the same time in MVC as in console app? It might be usefull to verify that code executes the same SQL and returns the same result. And SQL Server Profiler can show it

Comment: It is difficult to say what or if there is a problem from that you've posted. One thing to keep in mind is that the SqlDataReader will begin reading rows as soon as the first one arrives, so your "timing" of ExecuteReader() is not meaningful. If you want to get a handle on things, you should consume the entire data reader, then perform the file writing. In this way you can see where to concentrate your efforts.

Comment: Does the stored procedure always return the same number of rows and are you always running in the same environment?  I notice your Debug.WriteLine methods aren't giving a good indication of just how much data is being read each time.  So if the 14 minute run was 200k rows, then I would almost expect the 30 minute run to be nearly 400k.  Analyzing this would give you an idea if there actually is an inefficiency.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov When I run the console application the execution of the stored procedure appears instantly in SQL Server Profiler. I started running  the MVC application ten minutes ago and the execution of the stored procedure is still not present in SQL Server Profiler. Would you be able to give any advice as to what would be causing the delay in the execution of the stored procedure in the MVC application?

Comment: @cmcquillan The stored procedure always returns the same number of rows and the files that are produced from the MVC application and Console application match exactly.

Comment: Its hard to suggest something specific. You can also try to use .Net profiler like JetBrains dotTrace or similar to trace your code and try to get execution details line by line, so you might get more details for the issue

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Sorry I need to correct my previous comment. There wasn't a delay in the execution of the stored procedure. SQL Server Profiler shows that the execution of the stored procedure did start at the correct time, but it took roughly 25 minutes. The stored procedure executes in SSMS and the console application in 4 minutes.

Comment: hm, its strange that the same stored procedure executes different time, as SQL server doesn't know too much about application that run SQL. May be connection string is different? Or maybe you execute this page a couple of times, so for each refresh it queues the same query and it makes load to SQL and more time to process result?

Answer (score 0):

The thread exit messages are from other threads on the web server, may not necessarily be your request thread (Since webservers are multi-threaded)

Try using a StringBuilder and than writing everything to the file using System.IO.File.WriteAllText instead of using a file stream
If you need to append to an existing file System.IO.File.AppendAllText would work as well

Also, for SQL try using a SqlDataAdapter and copying the entire result into a DataSet and using Table[0] to loop through the data

Hope this explains